# Show Matrix Report in Dashboard

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I created a new matrix report with 2 groupings and summary fields, and now I'm trying to put it in my dashboard with exactly the same layout and format. I played around with Table component settings but couldn't get it working :( 
Thanks and appreciate for your time and help.

Comment: Bit more information? Kind of objects/Reportype? Some screenshot? Any error appear? Those things could be helpful :)

Comment: We need more votes on this idea so Salesforce knows this is something the community wants = https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kluUAAQ

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which reports can be displayed on dashboard - Metric and Table. Both won't work. Single grouping may work but 2 groupings not.

In case of charts the only way to represent a matrix report in dashboard is with a stacked or grouped bar chart. A dashboard will not show the correct matrix report any way.

Comment: Thanks regal, so there's really no way to show a matrix table report in Dashboard ?